# Is there a simple-to-implement datepicker for Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, datepicker

I'm working on a site in Symfony that displays graphs of a range of metrics.
Currently I'm trying to implement a simple datepicker to decide what graph to show.

Preferably in one of these forms:

- a simple calendar icon that presents a calendar when clicked
- three drop-downs for the day, month and year

The latter only as a plan-b really, the first would be great.

Now, I'm new to Symfony and I'm quite spoiled. Everything I wanted so far has always been but a plugin/helper/tag away. I sort of hoped that it was the same for a date-picker like this one, but so far I'm coming up empty. There are a few possibilities, but they all require a crap-load of dependencies and seem to have a low success-rate with people who have tried to implement them.

I have the feeling that I'm overlooking something that's right in front of me.
So in short: what is, according to you guys, the simplest way to implement such a date picker in Symfony? And if you have one, do you have a link with a clean and clear explanation?

Thanks a bunch,

Dieter

Comment: Alright, I got one to work. For people that might read this one day: I made a form class 'DateSelectForm' in /lib/form, which extends the BaseForm class. In there you need to make a configure() method, where you call $this->setWidget($name,$widget). $name is any name you want to use to get the value (for example 'date', $widget can be sfWidgetFormJQueryDate or the built-in sfWidgetFormDate. In your action you set $this->form = new DateSelectForm(), in the view you just do echo $form inside a form-tag, and you retrieve the value in your action as $request->getParameter('date'). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use sfWidgetFormJQueryDate widgets based on [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) from sfFormExtraPlugin.

```
class YourFormFilter extends BaseYourFormFilter
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $date_widget = new sfWidgetFormJQueryDate(array(
      'date_widget' => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%day%/%month%/%year%')),
      'culture' => 'ru'
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks m8. Do you, by any chance, know a place where that process is described? I'm not sure where to start, being a pretty big noob at Symfony. Apparently one has to do special stuff with forms, I gathered that much :) Maybe I should just read up on Symfony forms in general.

Comment: Start by installing the plugin by pear: ./symfony plugin:install sfFormExtraPlugin and read its [README](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormExtraPlugin), there's to an article for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one, it is intended for Syfmony2

http://blog.azancadas.com/2011/07/symfony2-datepicker/